# Different values (e.g. height or width) for different orientations in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a ListBox with `Height="515"`, when I turn my application, part of this ListBox is offscreen.

How to specify that ListBox's Height in landscape orientation should be, for example, 350 px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect orientation change

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.Portrait))
        {
            listbox.Height = 515;
        }
        else
        {
            listbox.Height = 350;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, there is no XAML-only solution? Like in Android dimensions.

Comment: I think not. Perhaps binding and IValueConverter would work, but you'd still need to write C# code... This is then the simplest way to go.

Comment: OK, also will add orientation changing transition here.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done as easily as in Android. However, if you would like to achieve a purely XAML-based solution for "proper" rendering then you could consider using a Grid layout container. The grid layout will repack the contained elements in the given page when orientation occurs.